# C# - How to decode a json array that does not contain any assignments

Tags: c#, json

I receive a json array that I need to decode:

```
[143084,[8906.3,24.990013919999996,8906.8,32.58931742,-32.6,-0.0036,8907,7171.16062768,9075,8620]]
```

It seems to be a valid json array but I am not sure how to decode it.
Usually I use:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(json);
```

but that doesn't work here because the json code has no "assignments", for the lack of a better word.
It should be like something this:

```
{
"channelId":"456456564",
"values":[ "8906.3,24.990013919999996,8906.8,32.58931742,-32.6,-0.0036,8907,7171.16062768,9075,8620" ]
}
```

I am not even sure what to google for because I do not know the correct word for

```
"channelId":
```

All examples use json arrays that look "normal" :/
Sorry for that vague question :/

Any help would be greatly appreceated! Thanks!

Comment: that is an array with an array.

Comment: You should deserialize it using `JArray.Parse`, and then grab the second item and convert it to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel A. White!

I ended up doing this:

```
message = message.Replace("[", "");
message = message.Replace("]", "");
var array = message.Split(',');
```

It gives me single level array that I can now convert into the object I need.
Might not be pretty, but works. Thanks Daniel!

Comment: As mentioned in comments above, you can `JArray.Parse`, then access its items

Comment: I don't like the idea of replace the text, if the json is well formatted is better to use a json reader and work with the possibles results, this way in the future less problems will happen @soomon

Comment: I agree, but json.parse does not work: Current JsonReader item is not an object: Integer. Path '', line 1, position 5. This site sais it is valid json though: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: Integer. Path '', line 1, position 4.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function something like this

```
        var jsonArray = @"[143084,[8906.3, 24.990013919999996, 8906.8, 32.58931742, -32.6, -0.0036, 8907, 7171.16062768, 9075, 8620]]";
        var deserializedArray = JArray.Parse(jsonArray);
        var result = new MyObject
        {
            channelId = deserializedArray.First.ToString(),
            values = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserializedArray.Last)
        };

        return result;
```

where MyObject looks like this:

```
    public class MyObject
    {
        public string channelId { get; set; }
        public string values { get; set; }
    }
```

This produces result:

```
{
  "channelId": "143084",

  "values": "[8906.3,24.990013919999996,8906.8,32.58931742,-32.6,-0.0036,8907,7171.16062768,9075,8620]"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that there are two options to you

1) Create a view model class that represents this

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public string channelId { get; set; }
  public string[] values { get; set; }
}
```

I'm considering that the values in the json is an array of strings with one value.

2) Use the JObject class like in this example

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm

Comment: Json.parse does not work: Current JsonReader item is not an object: Integer. Path '', line 1, position 5.

Comment: I didn't understand, can you post the complete code?